# kernel died when launching jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Python 3.6 with Anaconda 3.
The installation was successful however, when I launch a notebook, there is 
**kernel error** immediatly with the following error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 
1055, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", 
line 238, in result
raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 
1063, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 75, in post
type=mtype))
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 
1055, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", 
line 238, in result
raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 
1063, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in 
create_session
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, 
type, kernel_name)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 
1055, 
in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", 
line 238, in result
raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 
1063, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in 
start_kernel_for_session
self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 
1055, in run
value = future.result()
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", 
line 238, in result
raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 307, 
in wrapper
yielded = next(result)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 94, in 
start_kernel
super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 257, in start_kernel
**kw)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 203, in _launch_kernel
return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\Lionel\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in 
_execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
```

Note that before installing Anaconda 3, I uninstalled Anaconda 2 (with Python 2.7).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution in the web :

I had to execute the following command :

```
 python -m ipykernel install --user
```

Regards,

Lionel